# length is not defined in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to search for an object's attribute in JSON data.

But i am getting an error like `uncaught type error:length is not defined` in jQuery. My JSON looks like this:

```
var list = {
    meta: {
        limit: 1000,
        offset: 0,
        previous: null,
        total_count: 1797
    },
    objects: [{
        id: 1215,
        location: {
            id: 1306,
            name: "Austin",
            parent_id: 43,
            type: "City",
        },
        name: "2ND Street District",
    }]
};

$.each(list.objects.location, function (i, v) {
    if (v.id.search(new RegExp(/1036/i)) != -1) {
        alert(v.name);
        return;
    }
});
```

Give me any ideas about this issue.

Comment: posted an answer.Hope it solves your issue.Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects is a list then inside is the object(location) so you must use [0]

Change

```
$.each(list.objects.location
```

to

```
$.each(list.objects[0].location
```

**Update**

Try this

```
$(list.objects[0].location).each(function () {
    if (this.id.toString().match(/1036/g) != -1) {
        alert(this.name);
        return
    }
});
```

Comment: changed the code but still got another error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'search' of undefined at code.

Comment: hi just added a fiddle that shows ur data check out..http://jsbin.com/AZAhaWo/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code. First, you are not iterating over the array. The array ist `list.objects`, not `list.objects.location` (That's the reason you are getting the error `length is not defined`). So you have to change your `$.each()` call to this:

```
$.each(list.objects, function(i, v) {
```

Now you can use `v.location.id` to access the id of the current object. Her comes the next problem: It is an integer and it doesn't have a function `search()`, so we use `.test()` directly on the expression, it converts the integer to the needed string before testing and it returns the result as a boolean, which is exactly what you need here.

```
  if ( /1306/.test(v.location.id) ) {
    alert(v.name);
  }
});
```

See a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/vru89/1/)

Comment: I'd suggest `if ( /1036/.test(v.location.id) )` for increased clarity.

Comment: I think this looks even more complicated for a beginner

Comment: Debatable. That's both basic JS syntax. On the plus side, `test()` returns `true` or `false` right-away, so it's more idiomatic than `match()` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this fiddle will show all the data in location of object in json..check out http://jsbin.com/AZAhaWo/3/edit

```
$.each(list.objects[0].location, function(i, v) 
    {

       alert(v);

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

3 mistakes actually..2 mistakes in the json data ( though it doesn't matter but still)

```
 type: "City",
},
name: "2ND Street District",
```

should be

```
 type: "City"
},
name: "2ND Street District"
```

And change

```
$.each(list.objects.location, function(i, v) 
{
  if (v.id.search(new RegExp(/1036/i)) != -1) 
   {
    alert(v.name);
        return;
    }
});
```

to

```
$.each(list.objects, function (i, v) {
            if (v.location.id.toString().search(new RegExp(/1036/i)) != -1) {
                alert(v.location.name);
                return;
            }
        });
```

Hence your full code is as below:

```
 var list = {
            meta: {
                limit: 1000,
                offset: 0,
                previous: null,
                total_count: 1797
            },
            objects: [
                {
                    id: 1215,
                    location: {
                        id: 1306,
                        name: "Austin",
                        parent_id: 43,
                        type: "City"
                    },
                    name: "2ND Street District"
                }
                ]
        };

        $.each(list.objects, function (i, v) {

            if (v.location.id.toString().search(new RegExp(/1036/i)) != -1) {
                alert(v.location.name);
                return;
            }
        });
```

And here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KP8VR/)